# Customizing Body Text and Images using Markdown, Pandoc, Beamer to create PDF Slideshows

Tags: latex, markdown, pandoc, beamer

I have a series of markdown files that I am turning into slides using Pandoc and the Beamer template. I am creating my own custom Beamer template in order to format those slides.

```
pandoc --slide-level 2 -fmarkdown-implicit_figures -t beamer --template mytemplate.beamer -o test.pdf *.md
```

I am struggling with making certain elements look the way I would like them to.

My simplified markdown looks like this:

```
## Header

Normal Body Text

![Image](images/Image1.png "Image")
```

Specifically, my images are coming out left justified. I can't figure out how to get them to center. If I remove the `-fmarkdown-implicit_figures` option, then the images are properly centered, but includes captions that I don't want. Adding that flag eliminates the captions but also eliminates the centering.

At the same time, I want the normal body text to be centered as well. So in the above example I would like the text `Normal Body Text` to be centered. Again, I can't figure out how to do that. I have managed to center other elements (such as the header), but I can't find an appropriate name for the element that represents normal body text.

Can anyone offer a solution to either of these issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to center the images. It may not be the best option, but this seems to work:

```
\usepackage{letltxmacro}

% Save the meaning of \includegraphics
\LetLtxMacro\latexincludegraphics\includegraphics

% Update the include graphics command to include centering
\renewcommand{\includegraphics}[2][]{%
  \centering
  \latexincludegraphics[#1]{#2}}
```

To ensure the normal text was centered, I used the following, again I am unsure if this is the best way:

```
% Center Text By Default
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\centering
```